# Propagator for linear systems with bounded operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A:\mathbb{R} \to L(X,X)$, i.e $A(t)$ is an linear and bounded operator.
Furthermore there holds: $A(s)A(t)=A(t)A(s), \; \forall s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now define $u(t):=exp(-\int_{s}^t A(r) \,dr)\; u_0$,   with $u_0 \in X$ arbitrary and $exp(B):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^k}{k!}$ for $B \in X$.

I want to show that $u'(t)=-A(t)u(t)$:

$$u'(t)=exp(-\int_{s}^t A(r) \,dr)\, (-A(t))\,u_0=-A(t)\,exp(-\int_{s}^t A(r) \,dr)\, u_0$$

but why does the last equality holds? Why commutes everything?

Comment: If $A(t)$ commutes with $A(r)$ for every $r$ between $s$ and $t$ then it commutes with $\int_s^{t}A(r)dr$. Proof of this depends on what type of integral you are considering. What is your definition of the integral?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy   for $u:[a,b] \to X$ continuous the integral is defined as $\lim \int_{a}^{b} u_n(t) dt$ where $u_n$ is a step function. The integral for the step function is defined as usual.